# Proc tabulate, total in mid class variable

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get this result

```
-------------------------------------------
|       |        |        |   YES  |  NO  |
-------------------------------------------
|       |   A1   |  A11   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A12   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A2   |  A21   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A22   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|   A   |   A3   |  A31   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A32   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A4   |  A41   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A42   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |  TOTAL |        |   xxx  |  xx  |
-------------------------------------------
|       |   A1   |  A11   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A12   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A2   |  A21   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A22   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|   B   |   A3   |  A31   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A32   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A4   |  A41   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A42   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |  TOTAL |        |   xxx  |  xx  |
-------------------------------------------
|       |   A1   |  A11   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A12   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A2   |  A21   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A22   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|  TOT  |   A3   |  A31   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A32   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |   A4   |  A41   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |        |  A42   |   xxx  |  xx  |
|       |  TOTAL |        |   xxx  |  xx  |
-------------------------------------------
```

So I tried something like:

```
proc tabulate data = mydata;
class  var1 var2 var3 var4 ;
var counter;
table  var1*var2*var3 all , var4*counter*(sum);
run;
```

But also changing the table statement as:

```
   1) table  var1*(var2 all)*var3 all , var4*counter*(sum);
   2) table  var1*(var2*all)*var3 all , var4*counter*(sum);
```

But I keep having incorrect result since I'm searching for a subtotal on the second variable not affected by the third variable.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

the in the table statement try this:

```
table (var1 all)*(var2 all)*(var3), var4*counter*(sum)
```

if you also want a total for var3 just do this:

```
table (var1 all)*(var2 all)*(var3 all), var4*counter*(sum)
```

Comment: sorry, but you don't get the point. The total of var2 should have only one row for each var1. With the code you wrote, the "all" for var2 will have al the rows of var3...